# Starting visual studio with a specific project/solution

Tags: windows, visual-studio, scheduled-tasks

I have a [schedule a task](http://postimg.org/image/o29iqxgfx/), that task launches Visual Studio with administrator privileges and now I would like to give an argument which launches a specific project/solution(.sln file) on visual studio startup.

Is that possible, if not how ?

Ty

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Just pass the solution name with the path between quotes.

For example, from the command line:

```
devenv.exe "C:\YourPath\SolutionFile.sln"
```

For the scheduled task, in the arguments textbox add:

```
"C:\YourPath\SolutionFile.sln"
```